# How do I filter usernames that match API endpoints programatically?

Tags: node.js, twitter, api-design

Let's say that I'm developing an application similar to Twitter. I can see the profile of a user `tom` if I visit `https://twitter.com/tom`, but there are several application reserved endpoints like `/login`, `/logout`, `/settings`, `/about`, etc.

Twitter actually tells you the reason why you cannot take a certain username:
[image: This is the message you see when trying to take another user's username]
And I suppose the following message applies to reserved endpoints:
[image]

My question is: how does Twitter maintain a list of reserved endpoints for filtering out new registrations? It would appear that there is one check that matches the username against a list of registered users, and a second check that looks for reserved keywords.

Keeping a table with these keywords seems like an obvious answer, but I find one could easily forget to update after each creation of a top level (reserved) page.

Comment: Nice example username.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to get an answer to how Twitter does it because that would almost certainly require somebody to break an NDA. I would expect it to be a database table, but I have no inside information.

The preferred practice is to not overload a collection endpoint like that. Better would be

```
/users/tom
/login
/logout
...
```

Then your URI structure solves the problem for you.

Comment: Completely agree, hence not mentioning Twitter in the title. But I'd like to know how one would tackle this in a pragmatic way. StackOverflow uses the `/users/tom` approach :)